# Calling JavaScript class from TypeScript : Uncaught TypeError ... is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, babeljs, atom-editor

I am trying to use a plain JavaScript class from [atom-select-list](https://github.com/atom/atom-select-list) package inside my TypeScript package for Atom ([link](https://github.com/aminya/atom-indent-detective/tree/Atom-Select-List)).

I added a [declaration](https://github.com/aminya/atom-indent-detective/blob/d64ecc1cf1308f8ca47ab1ee5463f7f19499d6c8/types/atom-select-list.d.ts#L1) for this 3rd party dependency and included it in my package like this:

```js
/// <reference path="../types/atom-select-list.d.ts"/>
import {SelectListView} from 'atom-select-list'; // copmiled to: `const atom_select_list_1 = require("atom-select-list");`
```

However, I get this error

```js
~\atom-indent-detective\dist\selector.js:11
Hide Stack Trace
TypeError: atom_select_list_1.SelectListView is not a constructor
    at Object.selector_show (~\atom-indent-detective\dist\selector.js:11:26)
    at HTMLElement.indentDetectiveChooseIndent (../lib/indent-detective.ts:1:12)
    at CommandRegistry.handleCommandEvent (~\atom-nightly\app-1.46.0-nightly8\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:349292)
    at CommandRegistry.dispatch (~\atom-nightly\app-1.46.0-nightly8\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:347767)
    at HTMLSpanElement.view.onclick (~\atom-indent-detective\dist\status.js:24:34)
```

which points to

```js
indentListView = new SelectListView(...) //  compiled to `indentListView = new atom_select_list_1.SelectListView({...`
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //// Linting Options - Uncomment options to get more features (usually more restrictive)
//        "strict": true, // includes all of the following and more
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    //    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
//    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowJs": true,

    //// Compilation options
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
//    "preserveConstEnums": true,
//    "sourceMap": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    "removeComments": true,


//    "jsx": "react",
//    "jsxFactory": "etch.dom",
    "lib": [
      "ES2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "target": "ES2018",

    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
//    "noLib": false,
//    "importHelpers": true, // if true you should add tslib to deps
//    "skipLibCheck": false,

    "outDir": "../dist"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

I `use babel` with the following config in my package.json:

```js
  "babel": {
    "presets": ["@babel/typescript"],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
      "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ],
    "ignore": ["node_modules", "src/test"]
  }
```

Comment: wrong import,  try `import SelectListView from 'atom-select-list';`

Comment: Using `import selectModule from 'atom-select-list';` and `new selectModule.SelectListView`, now I get this error: `TypeError: atom_select_list_1.default.SelectListView is not a constructor`

Comment: using `import SelectListView from 'atom-select-list';` with `new SelectListView` I get `Error: Invalid child node: undefined`. Also, I get `TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'SelectListView' as a type.` or `TS2351: This expression is not constructable.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using:

```js
import SelectListView from 'atom-select-list'
```

or

```js
const SelectListView = require('atom-select-list')
```